# Dynamic memory allocation for a triangular 2-D Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to initialize a 2-D array such that, every row has different number of elements.
Morever, the number of elements of a row depends on the number of elements in it's previous row.
For instance, 
the function governing the number of elements in a row be:

```
Rows(N)= 2*Rows(N-1) +1
```

where, Rows(N) is the number of cells in the Nth row.

The problem can be solved easily, if i can find the size of an array.
for instance,
I tried:

```
int A[10];
```

then it's size is `sizeof(A)/sizeof(int)`, it gives me 10. (correct)

But if I allocate memory like:

```
int *A;
A=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

and then check the value of `sizeof(A)/sizeof(int)`, it gives me 1.(wrong)
So, this approach doesn't work here.

Can anybody help me on this one.

Comment: `A` is a pointer. `sizeof(A)` returns correctly the size of the pointer, not of the thing pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

While you can access dynamic memory like an array in C, it has different semantics. When you ask for `sizeof(A)/sizeof(int)`, you're actually asking `sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)`. Since those two quantities are equal (e.g. both 32-bit), the answer is `1`.

With dynamic memory the length of the "array" is not known at compile-time, so you need to explicitly store it in a separate variable. Alternatively, you could wrap the memory and its length in a struct (or a pointer to the struct) around as a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Either you count the elements in your array with a loop.

Or given

```
int *A; A=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

it seems you already know the size (10), so while you are building the rest of the array, use a variable to keep track the number of elements to go in the next row.

Comment: No, I don't know the number of elements. 
I was giving an example that, I am not able to get the sizeof array by:
sizeof(<ArrayName>)/sizeof(int)
where <ArrayName> is the arrayname variable.

Comment: I assume you will know the size of the first row of the array (otherwise how can the number grow by your formula).

So you use your formula to calculate the size of the next row in each iteration of your loop. I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` is an `int*`.  Arrays really are just a pointer to the first element of a contiguous memory block, there is no size information associated.  This means that `sizeof(A)` is the size of the single element.

Since you already have the size of the array, your code should work just fine with that.